# Nested struct bitfield alignment in GCC

Tags: c++, gcc

I'm using g++ (GCC) 4.7.2.20121109 and I'd like to have a nested struct aligned with bit boundary. Let me give an example:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

typedef struct {
   unsigned int a : 1;
   unsigned int b : 7;
} __attribute__( ( packed ) ) myType1;

typedef struct {
   unsigned int a : 1;
   struct {
      unsigned int b : 7;
   } __attribute__( ( packed ) );
} __attribute__( ( packed ) ) myType2;

int main(void)
{
   cout << "sizeof( myType1 ) = " << sizeof( myType1 ) << endl;
   cout << "sizeof( myType2 ) = " << sizeof( myType2 ) << endl;
}
```

Compiling with *"g++ filename.cpp -o output"*, gives me:

```
sizeof( myType1 ) = 1
sizeof( myType2 ) = 2
```

myType1 has the size that I'm expecting but myType2 hasn't. I'd like that sizeof( myType2 ) were 1 instead of 2. Is it possible?

Comment: Not an expert but I don't think this is possible because even if the inner structure of `myType2` is anonymous, it is still a structure, so you need to be able to address it, and thus it needs to be aligned to at least `sizeof(char)`.

Comment: the nested strcuct is not a bitfield any longer and should follow the alignment requirements. So, i do not think that it is possible. BTW, you do not need the attribute on the nested strcuct.

Comment: @Serge If I do not use `__attribute__( ( packed ) )` in the nested struct, the sizeof is 5 instead of 2.

Comment: hmm, then gcc documentation is not correct :(

Comment: you can use -Wpadding to see what the compiler is doing (clang++ is more verbose than g++). With -Wpedantic compiler complains that anonymous struct is a GNUextension. A good reference on structure padding is http://www.catb.org/esr/structure-packing/ . However, the described behavior is still a mystery for me.

Answer (score 0):

The anonymous nested struct declares a new class object, so any bitfields within it will be independent of any bitfields in the outer class.  Within a class, bitfields are "packed into some addressable allocation unit".  This packing does not span distinct objects within a class.

Then there's this from [class.bit] in the language spec:

> Allocation of bit-fields within a class object is implementation-defined. Alignment of bit-fields is implementation-defined.

which means the compiler is free to do with bitfields whatever it feels like (although this behavior does need to be documented).